# Redis with sidekiq weird behavior

Tags: redis, sidekiq

I'm using redis with sidekiq on my rails app, and I'm seeing weird behaviors :

lots of connection resets, and also time spent on redis is often above 1 sec per request.

I'm running rails 4.2.7.1, ruby 2.3.1
sidekiq 4.2.8
redis 3.2.1 (recently downgraded from 3.3.2)
it's running on heroku

any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to Sidekiq 4.2.9.

Comment: just did, I'll tell you how it went. Was there a known bug on 4.2.8 ?

Comment: Please read the changelog https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md#429